# адаптивные изображения wordpress?

Tags: wordpress

при вставке из админ панели на страницу изображения не адаптивны. что прописать нужно в functions чтобы исправить это?
WordPress 4.9.4

Comment: в стилях пропиши img{ max-width:100%; }

Comment: @Даниил и ещё "height: auto" чтобы не искажались пропорции, верно?

Comment: Экспериментируй.

Answer (score 0):

У себя сделал так, установите свой размер экрана и при необходимости класс.

```
@media (max-width: 470px) {
  img { width: 100%; }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

ВП по умолчанию (если не поломано плагинами/темой) выводит изображения с [srcset](https://webref.ru/html/img/srcset), что автоматически показывает нужные изображения для нужных экранов.

Метод же выводом через `@media` не очень хороший (нужно применять аккуратно), тк при этом грузятся все изображения.